# iOS ambient notifications in status bar like new Twitter app

Tags: ios5, xcode4, ios6

I am trying to recreate the same in app notifications that the new twitter app has, they call them Ambient Notifications. I've search through apples documentation for both iOS 5 and 6, but I haven't found anything useful, or even relevant. If someone has done this before and could give me an example? I can work off that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also searching for same as my client want same functionality in our app but still no luck.but meanwhile you can use this library to achieve your goal https://github.com/brunow/BWStatusBarOverlay

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show a notification in the iOS Status Bar, I would advise you to use [CWStatusBarNotification](https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWStatusBarNotification), which can be added to your Xcode project using [Cocoa Pods](http://www.cocoapods.org).

You can set parameters, like the duration, background color, text color, animation style, etc.